# Postfix - SASLAuthentication Problems Cram-MD5 with StartTLS

Tags: debian, email, postfix, saslauthd, starttls

Recently I configured my mail server which uses Postfix and Courier. Everything works except for the authentication when sending mail via my Postfix server(running on port 587) which has StartTLS enabled and uses SASLAuthentication with virtual domains and maps.

## Logs

When I try to connect with my e-mail client to send a message I get the following messages to show up in /var/log/mail.log:

```
postfix/smtpd[5108]: connect from ip domain.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
postfix/smtpd[5108]: Anonymous TLS connection established from domain.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
postfix/smtpd[5108]: warning: domain.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: SASL CRAM-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure
postfix/smtpd[5108]: disconnect from domain.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
```

## Configuration

**/etc/postfix/main.cf:**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/private/domain_com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/domain.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/private/certificates.ca-bundle
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
myhostname = domain.com
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/virtual_domains
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_maps
virtual_minimum_uid = 100
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
myorigin = domain.com
mydestination = domain.com, localhost.com, , localhost
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
        permit
smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
        reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
        reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous noplaintext 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
```

**/etc/default/saslauthd**:

```
START=yes
PWDIR="/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
PARAMS="-m ${PWDIR}"
PIDFILE="${PWDIR}/saslauthd.pid"
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="rimap"
MECH_OPTIONS="127.0.0.1"
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-c -r -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

## Directories

ls /etc/postfix/sasl/:

```
(empty)
```

ls /etc/postfix/:

```
dynamicmaps.cf  main.cf  master.cf  postfix-files  postfix-script  post-install  sasl  smtpd.conf  virtual.db  virtual_domains  virtual_maps  virtual_maps.db
```

ls /etc/courier/:

```
authdaemonrc  imapd  imapd.cnf  imapd-ssl  shared  userdb  userdb.dat  userdb.lock  userdbshadow.dat
```

## Notes

- The whole authentication with userdb for the courier server via imaps works perfectly fine. So there has to be some problem with my postfix configuration.

## Questions

1. How can I fix my configuration, to make the authentication function.
2. Is it possible to debug the SASLAuthentication, it only tells me if it's successful or not, but not that for example the username can't be found.

If you need any more information, please don't hesitate to ask. If you notice something weird about my configuration or if you have any suggestions for improvement also please let me know. Thank you very much. Any help is greatly appreciate it.

Comment: These lines are messed up: `mydestination = domain.com, localhost.com, , localhost` and you're missing something after that line as well. Also, try setting `smtpd_tls_security_level` to `may` and see if the error remains..

Comment: BTW, you may not have the libraries installed for the method you need, try doing a `yum install cyrus-sasl-*`

Comment: I have the following sasl packages installed:

`cyrus-sasl2-dbg,cyrus-sasl2-mit-dbg,libgsasl7,libqca2-plugin-cyrus-sasl,libsasl2-2:amd64,libsasl2-modules:amd64,libsasl2-modules-,ssapi-mit:amd64,sasl2-bin`

I changed the mydestination to:
mydestination = domain.com localhost

Still have the same error message. Rebooted the whole server to be sure that all services were reloaded.

Comment: have a look and see if there is something like `cyrus-sasl2-md5` available to install..

Comment: Did you see in your main.cf there is an extra comma in mydestination?

Comment: Also the lines afterwards are missing, I assume it's just a typo when you pasted things in?

Comment: Now the configuration file says:

`myorigin = domain.com`
`mydestination = domain.com localhost`
`smtpd_helo_restrictions = reject_invalid_helo_hostname,`
`reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,`
`reject_unknown_helo_hostname`
So I think it should be okay now, I removed the extra comma and deleted the other lines since I didn`t see what they were doing.
I can't seem to find a `cyrus-sasl2-md5` package though.

Comment: Try `yum search cyrus-sasl-*` and see what it comes back with

Comment: BTW, I assume you're using RH/CentOS, if not, the packages may have slightly different names.

Comment: I'm running Debian 7.0
If I run apt-cache search cyrus-sasl-* I get this:

cyrus-sasl2-dbg - Cyrus SASL - debugging symbols
cyrus-sasl2-doc - Cyrus SASL - documentation
cyrus-sasl2-heimdal-dbg - Cyrus SASL - debugging symbols for Heimdal modules
cyrus-sasl2-mit-dbg - Cyrus SASL - debugging symbols for MIT modules
libqca2-plugin-cyrus-sasl - QCA Cyrus SASL plugin for libqca2

Comment: if you set `smtpd_tls_security_level` to `may` then restart postfix, what happens?

Comment: Tried that, didn't have any effect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9582/discussion-between-nickw-and-misha-rogalla)